# Having trouble with a table not appearing on my site, any idea what is wrong?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/head.php';
include 'includes/navigation.php';
include 'includes/headerpartial.php';
?>

<div class="col-md-12">
      <h2 class="text-center">My Shopping Cart</h2><hr>
  <div class="">

    <?php if($cart_id == ''): ?>
      <div class="" >
        <p class="text-center text-danger">
          Your shoppping cart is empty!
        </p>
      </div>
        <?php else: ?>
          <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
            <thead><th>#</th><th>Item</th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Size</th><th>Sub Total</th></thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
        <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
```

the only thing that appears on my site is this https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TSfw.png

I edited the full code to this file.

also the $cart_id is currently supposed to be an empty string.

*edit after I edited the code everything is now aligned in the center https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GbaW.jpg

Comment: Have you checked to if $cart_id is actually empty?

Comment: The text "your shopping card is empty" is there, just in the corner of the screen - so you may have a CSS issue. And clearly $card_id is the empty string - if it shouldn't be, you haven't given us enough code to be able to diagnose why it is.

Comment: Just remove semicolon on this line `<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: sadly removing the semicolon did not fix it, I have managed to fix some of it by moving some code around.

Comment: I found out the problem <?php else: ?> as soon as i removed this the table appeared, any idea why?